# 'Album.Type' is not convertible to '() -> Album'

Tags: swift, swiftui

**So I'm passing data into another SwiftUI class, `Album()`:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject var model = PostListViewModel()
  @ObservedObject var model2 = PostListViewByIdModel()

        var body: some View {

            NavigationView {
                List(model.posts) { post in
                 VStack{
                        Text("Title: ").bold()
                            + Text("\(post.title)")
                    NavigationLink(destination: Album(post: post, post2: self.model2.postsById)) {
```

I'm getting this error on line `Album(post: post, post2: self.model2.postsById)`: `'Album.Type' is not convertible to '() -> Album'`

**Here is Album**

```
var mainArray:[PostById] = []
struct Album: View {
    var post:Post?
    var post2:[PostById] = []
    @ObservedObject var model = PostListViewModel()
    @ObservedObject var model2 = PostListViewByIdModel()

    init() {
        if let posty = post {
          mainArray = self.post2.filter { i in i.album_id == posty.id }
           print("mainArray \(mainArray)")
        }
    }
```

It's because of the `init()` function right? How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `Album.init(post: Post, post2: [PostById])` if you want to call that initializer:

```
init(post: Post, post2: [PostById]) {
    self.post = post
    self.post2 = post2
    ... rest of your initialization
}
```

Note that your use of `mainArray` here indicates a serious design problem. Views are structs, and may be created or destroyed at any time by the system. Creating them should never create side effects such as modifying a global variable.

---

From your description, `mainArray` is just a property of Album:

import SwiftUI

```
struct Album: View {
    var post:Post?
    var post2:[PostById] = []

    var mainArray:[PostById]

    @ObservedObject var model = PostListViewModel()
    @ObservedObject var model2 = PostListViewByIdModel()

    init(post: Post, post2: [PostById]) {
        self.post = post
        self.post2 = post2
        if let posty = post {
            mainArray = self.post2.filter { i in i.album_id == posty.id }
        } else {
            mainArray = []
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is calling Album. Can I make it so Album is only called when visited?

Comment: Album is a View. It's part of the View hierarchy, and will be created at the point that SwiftUI needs it. If it's expensive to create (not render; that comes later; `body` doesn't have to be evaluated when you create the View), then you should rethink what you've put in it. Views need to be cheap to create in SwiftUI.

Comment: I think because of the init() it's getting called on the ContentView. How can I use this line 
`if let posty = post {
mainArray = self.post2.filter { i in i.album_id == posty.id }
print("mainArray \(mainArray)")
}` in `struct Album` and use `mainArray` in my List without defining mainArray as a global variable and without using init?

Comment: From your description, `mainArray` should just be a `State` variable of `Album`. But it's not clear how you're expecting to use it. If it's used by other Views than it should be a `Binding` or `ObservedObject`. If it's local to Album, then it should be `State`. It definitely shouldn't be global (and certainly not globally mutable by Views).

Comment: I'm using it in a List in Album like this `List(mainArray) { post in
                    Text("\(post.name ?? "title")")
}` so where do I put the if statement in my code?

Comment: Updated; in that case it's just a property of the View. If you don't want to compute it at `init` time, you could just compute it with a function in your List: (`List(computeMainArray()) { ... }`). Lazy is hard to do with structs, so if that were important, I would move this computation into a model object and pass it to the View.

Comment: I'm not getting anything printed when I print mainArray. I was told an easy method like this: `List(self.post2.filter { i in i.album_id == post.id }) { post in
    Text("\(post.name ?? "title")")
}` but this doesn't show anything either. Why do you think it's not showing anything?

Comment: I would expect that your filter is removing all elements. You'll need to debug it normally; take each step and verify that it's doing what you think it's doing. Split the view into simpler pieces, and test each piece (generally with a Preview). There's no magic answer; you have a bug.

Comment: How can I make sure post2 has data before using it because the data I get in post2 is fetched from my database

Comment: This is going well beyond what can be worked out in comments. Fetching data from a database (or network) and displaying it is exactly what all the WWDC videos on SwiftUI and Combine walk you through. I would start with the "wizard school" example that Apple gives, and build from there.

Comment: By "wizard school example," I mean https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/722/

Comment: I probably will view it. I asked the question here though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60837104/how-to-make-sure-data-in-variable-is-loaded-before-using-it